# opposite of contains in hamcrest

Tags: java, hamcrest

What is the opposite of contains?

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("b", "a", "c");
    // should fail, because "d" is not in the list

    expectedInList = new String[]{"a","b", "c", "d"};
    Assert.assertThat(list, Matchers.contains(expectedInList));


    // should fail, because a IS in the list
    shouldNotBeInList = Arrays.asList("a","e", "f", "d");
    Assert.assertThat(list, _does_not_contains_any_of_(shouldNotBeInList)));
```

what should be `_does_not_contains_any_of_`?

Comment: Can you just negate the `contains` method? i.e. `!contains(shouldNotBeInList)` I haven't done much of this, so I'm not sure if it'll work, but its worth a try.

Comment: @Michael Pickett: not(contains all elements) = contains not all elements

Comment: Are you using Hamcrest? If so, the syntax should be more like !anyOf(...). I think, just looking at the API as I've never used Hamcrest.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can combine three built-in matchers in the following way:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.everyItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isIn;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

@Test
public void hamcrestTest() throws Exception {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("b", "a", "c");
    List<String> shouldNotBeInList = Arrays.asList("a", "e", "f", "d");
    Assert.assertThat(list, everyItem(not(isIn(shouldNotBeInList))));
}
```

Executing this test will give you:

> Expected: every item is not one of {"a", "e", "f", "d"}
>   but: an item was "a"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have a related question about matcher strictness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015862/strict-matching-in-hamcrest

Comment: hmmm, and how to solve it for strings to check if a substring is not contained

Comment: after `hasItems()` method this is very counterintuitive. I was trying to use `not(hasItems())` fro a while with no success. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method :

```
public <T> Matcher<Iterable<? super T>> doesNotContainAnyOf(T... elements)
{
    Matcher<Iterable<? super T>> matcher = null;
    for(T e : elements)
    {
        matcher = matcher == null ?
            Matchers.not(Matchers.hasItem(e)) :
            Matchers.allOf(matcher, Matchers.not(Matchers.hasItem(e)));
    }
    return matcher;
}
```

With this test case :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
// True
MatcherAssert.assertThat(list, doesNotContainAnyOf("z","e", "f", "d"));
// False
MatcherAssert.assertThat(list, doesNotContainAnyOf("a","e", "f", "d"));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html), I can see a clunky way to do it.  There is probably a better way!  This tests whether the list doesn't contain `a`, and doesn't contain `b`, and ...

```
List<Matcher> individual_matchers = new ArrayList<Matcher>();
for( String s : shouldNotBeInList ) {
    individual_matchers.add(Matchers.not(Matchers.contains(s)); // might need to use Matchers.contains({s}) - not sure
}
Matcher none_we_do_not_want = Matchers.allOf(individual_matchers);
Assert.assertThat(list, none_we_do_not_want);
```

(haven't tested, probably buggy :/ hope it helps)

Answer (score 1):

I had a have the same issue. My solution was just inverted logic for this match.

Following you can see the snippet of code:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/posts?page=0&size=1")
                .with(httpBasic(magelan.getUserName(), magelan.getPassword()))
                .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/html;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(content().string(allOf(
                        containsString("First post")
                )))
                .andExpect(content().string(allOf(
                        not(containsString("Second post"))
                )));
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, one can use the following:

list - shouldNotBeInList should equal to the list itself (need to convert to set)

```
    Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>(list);
    strings.removeAll(shouldNotBeInList);

    Set<String> asSet = new HashSet<>(list);
    Assert.assertTrue(strings.equals(asSet));
```

But there should be a better way, I hope.